# how to get Salesforce Native app templates to show in Xcode

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am using Xcode 5 (and also have 4.x installed), I have installed the Salesforce SDK for iOS (V2) by following the instructions on GitHub, e.g., clone the repo and then running the install.sh which seemed to have completed successfully as I can open the project workspace in Xcode 5 and run the app in the simulator and on my device and it works well, which allows me to edit account records etc.
HOWEVER, I have watched a tutorial from DF 12 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_cTeuHRWRo) and in the tutorial, the user was able to select a few Salesforce templates when opening a new XCode project. I don't have this option, I can only see the normal templates, e.g., MasterDetail, Single View etc. from the "Choose a template for your new project" screen. 
My question is: how so I get the templates to show up in the template screen when starting a new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version, 2.0, of the Mobile SDK moves away from the Xcode templates in favor of the `forceios`/`forcedroid` command line tools for project creation. These tools are installed via npm - for example, on the Mac:

```
sudo npm install forceios -g
```

You then create a Mobile SDK app with

```
forceios create
```

You no longer need to pull the code from GitHub unless you want to modify the SDK. See the [Mobile SDK Development Guide](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf?raw=true) for more info.